# Getting Error object output not found when trying to render shiny flexdashboard from R script

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a shiny flexdashboard that runs fine if I open the file directly and click Run Document in R Studio, however I am trying to set up an R script to run the dashboard. The script will find the markdown file and run partly through it but always throws an error once it gets to something like `output$something <- renderUI(...)`. The error is

```
Error in output$select_file <- renderUI({ : object 'output' not found
```

A test markdown file for this issue is:

````
---
title: "example"
author: "hamburglar"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: yeti
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

#```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)

#```

Home
=======================================================================

Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

> These are some notes

#```{r}

data(iris)
data(cars)
data(CO2)
files <- list(iris=iris, cars=cars, CO2=CO2)

output$select_file <- renderUI({
  selectInput(inputId='file_choice', 
              label='Choose File', 
              choices=names(files)
              )
})

uiOutput("select_file")

#```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Data
#```{r}

renderTable({
  files[[input$file_choice]]
})


#```
````

And I've tried to use the following scripts with the same results:

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

render("path/test_board.Rmd", 
  #output_file="Dashboard.html"
  #flex_dashboard()
  #"flex_dashboard"
)
```

For the `path` I've tried a shared drive path and my desktop and I've tried a number of different arguments that I've read will let the render function know to make a flaexdashboard (in comments in the render function). In all my attempts I get the Error saying that the `output` object cant be found. If anyone could offer any help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In `flexdashboard` you don't need to use `output`. Just do:

````
---
title: "example"
author: "hamburglar"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: yeti
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)

```

Home
=======================================================================

Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

> These are some notes

```{r}

data(iris)
data(cars)
data(CO2)
files <- list(iris=iris, cars=cars, CO2=CO2)

selectInput(inputId='file_choice', 
              label='Choose File', 
              choices=names(files)
              )

```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Data
```{r}

renderTable({
  files[[input$file_choice]]
})

```
````

[image: result]

Comment: Hi @HubertL thanks for the response. If I take out the line `uiOutput("select_file")` I get the same error when I try to run by script and now I get an error when I try to run in R Studio: Error attempt to select less than one element in get1index

Comment: Also remove `output$select_file <- renderUI({`

Comment: Now I get Error: path for html_dependency not provided

Comment: Did you remove the `#` before the `\`\`\``?

Comment: Yes. Also I dont think this would work because, even though I failed to put it in the example, some of the inputs in my flax board are dependent on each other which I think does not work with the method youre describing.

Comment: Hi @HunterClark, I updated my answer with full code so you can check for error on your setup. As you can see, it works fine on my setup.